# Thinkpad x220 wireless network slows down after some time

Tags: wireless, networking, disconnect

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Thinkpad x220.

When I connect to a wireless network, the network speed starts out normal. But after a certain period of time (say, 10 minutes), the network speed progressively slows down. Eventually it disconnects completely, and I cannot even ping the router.

Why could this be happening? I have only had this problem with 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-11n-disable` with the following content and then rebooting.

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Also read the following bug reports to see if you have the same symptoms.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1036356
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1049257
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/994104

Answer (score 0):

This is happening on my lenovo u310 with Ubuntu LTS 12.04 as well. Any help would be very appreciated.

The only thing is that, I had tried to uninstall chromium browser completely, so after using synaptic package manager to uninstall packages, I had deleted chrome folders from AppData/local ans AppData/roaming. After that wifi crawls to a stop on any network in a few minutes.